# How to get the index of an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, json

The following JSON string shows the correctness of two questions submitted and I want to know the IDs of the two questions, namely the indices of the associatve arrays within "submission", "question1" and "question2". How am I supposed to do that? Thanks!

```php
<?php
$test = 
'{
    "event_source": "server",
    "event_type": "problem_check",
    "submission": {
        "question1":{
            "correct":false
        }
        "question2":{
            "correct":true
        }
    }
}';

$jarray = json_decode($test, true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.You json data have some missing `,` and `""` (check my output links for correct format)

2.Use `foreach()` if you want to show each question submission result.

```
$jarray = json_decode($test, true);

foreach($jarray['submission'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key. ' answer is '.$value['correct'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/T3sh4  OR https://3v4l.org/3lUNF

3.***If you want only keys*** then do:-

```
$questionIds = array_keys($jarray['submission']);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/f0oHq

References:-

[json_decode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

[foreach()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

[array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

Answer (score 2):

A rather simple approach but it should do the trick:

```
$i = 0;
foreach($jarray['submission'] as $key => $val) {
  echo $key " is the index ". $i;
  $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [array_keys()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)

```
$newArray = array_keys($test);
```